# How do I retain focus when the user clicks a menu?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, browser

I have the following requirements:

- Display an input field.
- Display a menu.
- When the input field has focus, show the menu.
- If the input field looses focus, hide the menu.
- If the menu is clicked, retain the menu even though the input field has lost focus.

To reproduce my issue:
 - Place cursor in the input field
 - Click the menu

Expected:
 - The menu is still visible

Actual:
 - The menu disappears

This should be straightforward in React, but I haven't been able to solve this in the most obvious way and would like to know what it is I'm overlooking.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.handleFocus = this.handleFocus.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
  }

  handleFocus() {
    this.setState({ hasFocus: true });
  }

  handleBlur() {
    this.setState({ hasFocus: false});
  }

  handleMenuClick() {
    this.setState({ hasFocus: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { hasFocus } = this.state;

    const menuInstance = (
      <div
        onClick={this.handleMenuClick}
        tabIndex="0"
      >
        Some menu
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Focus issue</h1>
        <p>How do I retain focus if the user clicks on the menu item?</p>
        <input
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          onFocus={this.handleFocus}
          defaultValue="some value"
        />
        { hasFocus && menuInstance }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Live demo here: http://jsbin.com/zixuhoj/6/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're listening for blur and click events. Blur events are fired before click events so your `handleMenuClick` will never be called.

Instead you can listen to `onMouseDown` and set a flag for `menuClicked` or something like that and look at that flag in the `blur` event.

Demo can be found here: http://jsbin.com/buzisepafu/1/edit?js,console,output

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.handleFocus = this.handleFocus.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
    this.handleMenuClick = this.handleMenuClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleFocus() {
    this.setState({ hasFocus: true });
  }

  handleBlur() {
    if (!this.state.menuClicked) {
      this.setState({ hasFocus: false});
    }
  }

  handleMenuClick (event) {
    this.setState({ menuClicked: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { hasFocus } = this.state;

    const menuInstance = (
      <div
        className="menu"
        onMouseDown={this.handleMenuClick}
        tabIndex="0"
      >
        Some menu
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Focus issue</h1>
        <p>How do I retain focus if the user clicks on the menu item?</p>
        <input
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          onFocus={this.handleFocus}
          defaultValue="some value"
        />
        { hasFocus && menuInstance }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a different approach that works in my environment where the users only have Chrome where I put the `onBlur` handler on the outer `div` and check if the `relatedElement` on the `blur` event is inside the outer `div` or not.

Feel free to ask if you'd like me to elaborate.